# How to know the ressource I'm using for an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I'm leaning Android by myself and i'm doing some useless soft like this one.

In my Activity I have an ImageView with a ressource set on. Also a button.
I would to change the ressource in my ImageView "OnClick"

XML :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myIcon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/assigned"
        android:layout_below="@id/orientation"/>
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/myIcon"
        android:text="button"
        android:onClick="onClick2"/>
```

Activity :

```
public void onClick2 (View view) {
       ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myIcon);
       if (image.equals(getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.assigned))) {
           image.setImageResource(R.drawable.initial);
       } else {
           image.setImageResource(R.drawable.assigned);
       }
   }
```

This code doesn't work, but I try really !

Any idea ? Maybe I'm not doing it the good way.

Thks.

Comment: Add information about what is not working ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

boolean flag = true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void onClick2 (View view) {
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myIcon);
    if (flag) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fly);
        flag = false;
    } else {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.funny);
        flag = true;
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: please change `Boolean flag` to `boolean flag`

Comment: @yaa110 you are right because AFAIK it is better for the memory and doesn't need check to verify that the variable is not null. Please If there are another reasons tell us . I'll Edit my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: As you mentioned, primitive types are more performance-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

you can set tag for your imageView

```
imageView.setTag(yourImageRessource);
```

and then

```
imageView.getTag();
```